# How to apply image effects to a JPEG in a memory buffer using LEADTOOLS 19

Tags: c++, bitmap, leadtools-sdk

I'm making a Windows executable using C++, LEADTOOLS19, and VS2015 to read an image from a server, apply an image effect to it using LEADTOOLS, and display it in a browser.

The server provides me the image as an array of chars containing the JPEG encoding of the image (starting with "ÿØÿà") and the length of this buffer. Most of the LEADTOOLS functions read images from files, but I don't want to have to write it to disk just to read it as a bitmap.

---

The first thing I tried was the StartFeedLoad function:

```
//pImageData is the buffer of JPEG data, and imageLength is the 
//server-provided size of pImageData in bytes
LBuffer buf((L_VOID *)pImageData, imageLength);
LFile   imgFile;
LBitmap bitmap;

imgFile.SetBitmap(&imgbitmap);

// Initialize the file-load process
imgmemfile.StartFeedLoad(8, 0,
    LOADFILE_ALLOCATE | LOADFILE_STORE, NULL);
imgmemfile.FeedLoad(&buf);
imgmemfile.StopFeedLoad();
```

With this code, I get this exception when trying to run StartFeedLoad:

```
Exception thrown at 0x000007F855BC2662 (ltwvcax.dll) in getimage.exe:
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000148.
```

I tried a few different things before calling StartFeedLoad, and tried changing the parameters I was passing it, but got that exception every time.

---

With that not working, the next method I tried was to save the buffer as an in-memory file using the LEADTOOLS library LMemoryFile class:

```
LBuffer buf((L_VOID *)pImageData, imageLength);
LMemoryFile imgmemfile;
BITMAPHANDLE pbit;

//The bitmap the image will be loaded into
LBitmap bitmap;
imgmemfile.SetBitmap(&bitmap);

//Load the buffer to the image
ret = imgmemfile.LoadMemory(buf, 0, ORDER_RGBORGRAY, LOADFILE_ALLOCATE |   LOADFILE_STORE, NULL);
```

At this point, LoadMemory returns WRPERR_INVALID_PARAMETERS:    One or more invalid parameters were specified. I've tried different bitsPerPixel values, color orders, and with or without adding another NULL parameter as fileInfo but still get the same error.

---

I feel like I need to do something else to "prep" the bitmap to load, but I don't know it's size or anything else to initialize it.

Thanks!

---

EDIT 5/9/16: Added "GetInfo" as indicated by Leadtools:

```
//Load image
LBuffer buf((L_VOID *)pImageData, imageLength);
//LFile imgmemfile;
FILEINFO fileInfo = FILEINFO(); 
LMemoryFile imgmemfile;
BITMAPHANDLE pbit;

if (LBase::GetLoadedLibraries() & LT_FIL == 0)
    return false; 

LBitmap bitmap;
imgmemfile.SetBitmap(&bitmap);
ret = imgmemfile.GetInfo(buf, &fileInfo, sizeof(FILEINFO), 0, NULL);
ret = imgmemfile.LoadMemory(buf, 0, ORDER_RGBORGRAY, LOADFILE_ALLOCATE | LOADFILE_STORE, NULL, &fileInfo);
ret = imgmemfile.Save(&buf, FILE_JPEG, 8, 30, NULL);
```

The code gets past the additional library check, but GetInfo returns -2041, indicating that LTFIL isn't loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions that LEADTOOLS Support gave me were correct, but I was still ahving the issue because I was linking to both the Unicode and ANSI versions of the Leadtools C++ class library (Ltwvc_x.lib AND Ltwvc_ax.lib). When I removed the Unicode library (from my ANSI project) everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should use LMemoryFile::GetInfo and LMemoryFile::LoadMemory if you have the whole file in memory at the start. If you don't, then FeedLoad is the way to go. There is an example here: https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/main/clib/lfile__startfeedload.html

You can find a full working example in your LEADTOOLS installation folder: C:\LEADTOOLS 19\Examples\ClassLibrary\MSVC\FeedLoad

Comment: Hey, I added a call to GetInfo, but it returns -2041, indicating that LTFIL isn't loaded. I added a check 

 if (LBase::GetLoadedLibraries() & LT_FIL == 0)
  return false; 

to the line before it, and it doesn't return false, indicating that LTFIL is loaded. Am I checking that correctly?